# How to Join in ObjectBox

Tags: android, objectbox

How can I join two classes in [ObjectBox](https://objectbox.io/) which have one two many relationship?
I have two tables as following:
@Entity

```
public class Animal {
    @Id(assignable = true)
    public long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean flying;
    private boolean swimming;
    private boolean walking;
    private ToOne<Zoo> zoo;

.../*setters and getters*/

}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class Zoo {
    @Id
    public long id;
    private String name;
    // a Zoo can have many Animals
    @Backlink
    ToMany<Animal> animals;
.../*setters and getters*/

}
```

How can I implement Join operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version `2.0.0` you can do something like:

```
val builder = box.query().equal(Zoo_.name, "The Big Zoo")
builder.link(Zoo_.animals).equal(Animal_.flying, true)
val flyingAnimals = builder.build().find()
```

This is called ["links" and there is documentation](https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#add-query-conditions-for-related-entities-links) on it with an additional example.